# Sort Multidimensional Array by Alphanumeric value in Magento 2.4.6

Tags: php, array, magento2.4.6

**For Example, my Array is something like this :**

```
$testArray = [
    "01-01A" => [
        'name' => "test1",
        'test' => "01-01A"
    ],
    "01-06B" => [
        'name' => "test2",
        'test' => "01-06B"
    ],
    "02-05A" => [
        'name' => "test3",
        'test' => "01-05A"
    ],
    "03-33B" => [
        'name' => "test4",
        'test' => "01-33B"
    ],
    "01-044B" => [
        'name' => "test5",
        'test' => "01-044B"
    ],
    "07-098A" => [
        'name' => "test1",
        'test' => "01-098A"
    ],
    "09-0963B" => [
        'name' => "test2",
        'test' => "01-0963B"
    ],
    "10-0596C" => [
        'name' => "test3",
        'test' => "01-0596C"
    ],
    "99-0586C" => [
        'name' => "test4",
        'test' => "01-0586C"
    ],
    "21-984E" => [
        'name' => "test5",
        'test' => "01-984E"
    ]
];
```

> How can I sort this array using a key or 'test' ??

**Output:**

```
01-01A
01-05A
01-098A
01-06B
01-33B
01-044B
01-0963B
01-0586C
01-0596C
01-984E
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution :**

```
uksort($testArray, function ($key1, $key2) {
    // Extract letters from keys
    $letter1 = substr($key1, -1);
    $letter2 = substr($key2, -1);
    // Compare letters
    $letterComparison = strcmp($letter1, $letter2);
    // If letters are the same, sort by numeric part of keys
    if ($letterComparison === 0) {
        $numericPart1 = (int) substr($key1, 3, -1); // Extract numeric part of key1
        $numericPart2 = (int) substr($key2, 3, -1); // Extract numeric part of key2
        return $numericPart1 - $numericPart2; // Compare numeric parts
    }
    return $letterComparison;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge,This will not sort because key "test" value is a combination of `numeric`, `string` and `dash`.

If you change key "test" value without dash then `natsort()` function will sort the array having value(numeric with string).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the simplest way you can try:

```
<?php

$testArray = [
    "01-01A" => [
        'name' => "test1",
        'test' => "01-01A"
    ],
    "01-06B" => [
        'name' => "test2",
        'test' => "01-06B"
    ],
    "02-05A" => [
        'name' => "test3",
        'test' => "01-05A"
    ],
    "03-33B" => [
        'name' => "test4",
        'test' => "01-33B"
    ],
    "01-044B" => [
        'name' => "test5",
        'test' => "01-044B"
    ],
    "07-098A" => [
        'name' => "test1",
        'test' => "01-098A"
    ],
    "09-0963B" => [
        'name' => "test2",
        'test' => "01-0963B"
    ],
    "10-0596C" => [
        'name' => "test3",
        'test' => "01-0596C"
    ],
    "99-0586C" => [
        'name' => "test4",
        'test' => "01-0586C"
    ],
    "21-984E" => [
        'name' => "test5",
        'test' => "01-984E"
    ]
];

// get name as an separate array
$name = array_column($testArray, 'name');
// sorting $testArray ascending base on `name`
array_multisort($name, SORT_ASC, $testArray);

print_r($testArray);
```

**and the result will be:**

```
Array
(
    [01-01A] => Array
        (
            [name] => test1
            [test] => 01-01A
        )

    [07-098A] => Array
        (
            [name] => test1
            [test] => 01-098A
        )

    [01-06B] => Array
        (
            [name] => test2
            [test] => 01-06B
        )

    [09-0963B] => Array
        (
            [name] => test2
            [test] => 01-0963B
        )

    [10-0596C] => Array
        (
            [name] => test3
            [test] => 01-0596C
        )

    [02-05A] => Array
        (
            [name] => test3
            [test] => 01-05A
        )

    [99-0586C] => Array
        (
            [name] => test4
            [test] => 01-0586C
        )

    [03-33B] => Array
        (
            [name] => test4
            [test] => 01-33B
        )

    [01-044B] => Array
        (
            [name] => test5
            [test] => 01-044B
        )

    [21-984E] => Array
        (
            [name] => test5
            [test] => 01-984E
        )

)
```

Comment: How can I sort this array using a key or 'test' ??

Comment: just need to change the `name` to `test` =>


`// get name as an separate array`  
`$name = array_column($testArray, 'name');`  
`// sorting $testArray ascending base on test`  
`array_multisort($name, SORT_ASC, $testArray);`  
  
`print_r($testArray);`